# how do you create s3 subdirectories using aws cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

if I wanted to create a bucket with a layout like this:

```
bucket/
├─ subdir-1/
│  ├─ subsubdir-1/
├─ subdir-2/
├─ subdir-3/
```

how could I do this using the cdk? Or even a yml cf template?

Comment: You don't need to pre-create that folder structure at all. A client application can simply upload an object to `subdir_1/cat.png`, for example. That aside, as a general rule you can't do this directly when creating infrastructure because these aren't infrastructure resources. If you really, really need them then you could use a custom resource (basically a Lambda function that can run arbitrary code).

Comment: Oh that's super interesting. I didn't know the bucket automatically creates the directory. Thanks!

Comment: Uploading an object doesn't actually create the relevant directory/folder. It's not needed. S3 is an object storage system where the 'filenames' are simply keys. It doesn't operate like a typical block storage file system though the tooling makes it look that way because it's familiar to most people. If an object exists at `folder1/dog.png` then `folder1/` is inferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you do not need to create directories/template. When you use SDK/CLI to upload an object, it will automatically create the folder/structure matching the key used when uploading the object. You may be able to create empty directories through CLI/SDK but I don't think aws-cdk would do that as it is not supposed to managed the content of S3.

If you really want to maintain a certain layout for the bucket, you could use bucket policy to only allow certain directory when the SDK/CLI put your object to S3. This policy could be added on the aws-cdk (Ref: [aws-cdk-s3-docs-addPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3.Bucket.html#addwbrtowbrresourcewbrpolicypermission)). Policy example as follows.

```
{
  "Sid": "Layout",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action": "s3:PutObject*",
  "NotResource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::{BUCKET_NAME}/subdir-1/subsubdir-1/*",
    "arn:aws:s3:::{BUCKET_NAME}/subdir-2/*",
    "arn:aws:s3:::{BUCKET_NAME}/subdir-3/*",
  ]
}
```

More detail on s3 bucket policy: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html